# Purpose of on Droid in graphql?

Tags: graphql

I am new to Graphql. I go through the grapql docs https://graphql.org/learn/queries/#inline-fragments

```
query HeroForEpisode($ep: Episode!) {
  hero(episode: $ep) {
    name
    ... on Droid {
      primaryFunction
    }
    ... on Human {
      height
    }
  }
}
```

what is Droid and Human here?

Comment: Did you read the text _below_ the example? They're just examples of types, where you'd pull different properties depending on which it is.

Comment: It mentioned as the hero field returns the type Character, which might be either a Human or a Droid depending on the episode argument. what is character here?

Comment: It's also a type, as the text says. The model is a movie - in Star Wars some of the _characters_ are _humans_, some _droids_, some other things (e.g. _aliens_). The _hero_ is a _character_ and all _characters_ have _names_, but only if the _hero_ is a _droid_ do they have a _primary function_. I don't know if your question is about GraphQL so much understanding the thing being modelled, which isn't really a programming question.

Answer (score 0):

They are GraphQL object type names.

The corresponding GraphQL SDL is in the [Interfaces section of the "Schemas and Types" page](https://graphql.org/learn/schema/#interfaces).  The minimum interesting part of the schema is

```
interface Character { ... }
type Human implements Character { ... }
type Droid implements Character { ... }
```

So in this query the `hero` field has the interface type `Character`, and the `... on SomeTypeName` syntax lets you pick out the fields from a specific implementation type if the actual value is that type.